# Force browser to insert <p> tag when pressing Enter in a designMode IFrame

Tags: html, iframe, designmode

How can I make the browser insert `<p>` tags instead of `<br>` tags when I press enter in a `designMode` IFrame? I get inconsistent behavior across Firefox, Chrome and IE and was wondering if there was some way to normalize this.

Comment: You say designMode iFrame- did you mean textarea? Also, are you using any Javascript libraries (like jQuery)?

Comment: I mean IFrame with `designMode = 'on'`, so the WYSIWYG textarea type thing, and yes, I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can't. Behaviour is not standardized and control for this is rudimentary at best

This is an interesting thread from May thie year on the matter: http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-May/031577.html  . It's discussing contenteditable rather than designMode but they're effectively very similar.

An email on the thread ( http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-May/031604.html ) from Simon Pieters (zcorpan) of Opera says:

> Opera 11.10 has introduced
>   document.execCommand('opera-defaultblock','','div') to switch to using
>   `<div`>s instead of `<p>`s. ('p' is also allowed to switch back.) Apparently
>   WebKit considers implementing this as well.
>   https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=59961

Further in the thread there's also this email http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-May/031685.html by Markus Ernst including this comment:

> I assume there are use cases for both generating `<p>`s and `<br>`s. The 
>   IE/Opera approach has the advantage of allowing both, which is perfect
>   for text and basic HTML editing. From a WYSIWYG POV it might be best
>   to  offer both options, so authors are not encouraged to add
>   server-side  processing to change the output, which would break
>   WYSIWYG.
>
> If the behavior is settable, it might even be a good idea to leave the
>   choice of the standard behavior to the UAs. Authors who have a reason
>   to  care can set their preferred behavior, while other authors might
>   prefer  to leave it as it was, so there is no change for their
>   existing users.

There's lots more on the thread about what people at the various browser makers think ought to happen, comments on some very strange existing behaviours, and general discussion about the problem involved in implementing it at all.

The currently very alpha spec for all this is at http://aryeh.name/spec/editing/editing.html

Comment: I've looked at CKEditor and TinyMCE and they both seem to be able to force the browser to insert `<p>` tags over `<br>` tags -- any idea how that's implemented? (and no, I can't really just use one of those editors)

Comment: The thread does mention this. I think it says they capture and override the enter key and apply their own set of actions instead. But it didn't go into detail as far as I could see.